# Why am I getting "Connection reset by peer" with Indy only on a HTTPS (SSL) site?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, indy

I am trying to use Indy HTTP (Delphi Seattle) to get the contents of a https webpage and I always seem to get Error 10054 - Connection reset by peer. Other sites seem to work just fine. The website in cause is *https://www.adultwork.com*. I have added the SSL, Cookie and Compressor components, but maybe I'm missing something, some settings, IDK... If anybody could help, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: are you using the openssl dll's and if so, from where did you get them?

Comment: Initially I've got the dlls from some older projects which as far as I can remember are from the same place I've tried to get some new ones now, meaning from indy.fulgan.com/SSL/ and now I've now got "openssl-0.9.8s-i386-win32.zip". Older ones are probably just another version from the same place.

Comment: @ChinaWhite why are you using OpenSSL 0.9.8s? That is very old. You should be using 1.0.2o instead. It is available at the same Fulgan URL

Comment: Mea culpa, I guess I was tired and thought the first there in the list was actually the last... After reading some more about OpenSSL I got the newer ones from another place and after reading your comment, I saw that the new ones are there also. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 8):

I was able to reproduce the issue, and it is due to Indy's `TIdIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL` component [only enabling TLS v1.0 by default](https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/issues/181).

Like many other sites nowadays, AdultWorks does not accept TLS 1.0 anymore.  In fact, it doesn't accept TLS 1.1, either.  It requires TLS 1.2.  Once I enabled TLS 1.2 in the IOHandler's `SSLVersions` property, `TIdHTTP.Get()` was able to access the site without error.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks both for pointing in the right direction! Seems like besides the TLS 1.2 part, I was also using outdated dlls. Using updated dlls and the TLS 1.2 version made things work.